# Javascript: Adding a property to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
var myarray=[{"name":"John","address":"home"},{"name":"Peter","address":"home"}]
```

and I would like to run a function to add a property to the array as follows:

```
[{"name":"John","address":"home","collection":"friend"},
 {"name":"Peter","address":"home","collection":"friend"}]
```

I have tried doing this:

```
myarray=myarray.map(function (err, myarray){
    myarray.collection="friend";
    return myarray;
}
console.log(myarray)
```

But the console continues to return this:

```
[{0},{1}]
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: Basic debugging with `console.log()` would reveal the issue.

Comment: I've reproduced my console message in the question and don't see what issues it was revealing.

Comment: The code shown doesn't produce the output that you claim, it returns `[0, 1]` (assuming you fix the missing `)` syntax error). If you'd tried `console.log(myarray)` inside the callback you'd have seen why.

Comment: even if it shows [0,1] I don't see how that 'reveals' the issue

Comment: So you expected an array of objects *(in fact claimed that was the output)*, yet getting an array of indices instead reveals nothing to you? Not even enough to get you to do more logging in the callback? Oy vey...

Comment: all it logs is an array. the numbers could be numbers, boolean, string as far as i know. so it did not reveal anything to me. I also have no idea what you mean by 'logging in the callback'. If i knew I wouldn't be asking the question here and run the of risk of getting penalised by ppl who think i should be able to work it out by console logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not adding the property to the contents of the array. The values of the array are given as the first parameter to the callback function (the second parameter is an index, and not the array itself—that's the third parameter). Simply assign the new property to the first parameter of the callback function, rather than the second one.

*Edit* - As @zerkms points out, however, if you're looking to update the current array rather than generate a new array, `map` is probably not best solution here. [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) provides a method for iterating over the current array, and modifying each of its values (which is what you're doing). This would looks omething like this:

```
myarray.forEach(function(value) {
    value.collection = "friend";
});
```

---

As you'll notice in the documentation for [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), the callback function returns the new value that will appear in the new array that is generated by `map`; if you're changing the current array in place (i.e. by modifying the properties of its contents), there's no need to return anything.

```
myarray.map(function(value) {
    value.collection = "friend";
});
```

Also note that both `map` and `forEach` are methods, so you need to close the method invocation with `)`.

Comment: Its not adding to the array, but to the temporary indices. Inside the function, `myarray` is an index.

Comment: It's super misleading to use `map` to mutate an array it's called on. Instead one must use `Array.prototype.forEach`

Comment: @Syntac Good point, got the argument order confused a bit there.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the suggestion, you're absolutely right that that's neither an intuitive nor an idiomatic usage of `map`.

Comment: thank you for this! Its helped me understand map a whole lot better.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong use of map().
The first argument of map() is the current element of the array, the second argument is it's index.
For example:

```
['a','b','c'].map(function(element, index){console.log(element, index)});
```

Will result in

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

So inside your function `myarray` was your index, and you were trying to add the property to the index.

Now you have to options. Either you use the `map()` as it's ment to be used and assign it's return value to `myarray`:

```
myarray = myarray.map(function(element) {
    element.collection = "friend";
    return element;
});
```

or you can, because objects are not getting copied but referenced when passed as an argument, not care about the return values and modify the elements directly:

```
myarray.map(function(element) {
    element.collection = "friend";
});   // returns [undefined, undefined ...]
```

This, however, isn't the way one should use `map()`

**Better: Use `forEach()`**

```
myarray.forEach(function(element) {
    element.collection = "friend";
});
```

Hope it helped.
Greets!

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is changing the reference object within map function

```
myarray.map(function (value){
  value.collection = "friend";
});

console.log(myarray);
```